# View doesn't adjust properly to keyboard

Tags: swift

I have a textfield that needs to be moved up when the keyboard displays and moved back down when it dismisses. The issue is this works only once. I am able to move it up and back down once and when I try to enable the view again the view doesn't adjust/move.

The code I am using is the following

```swift
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0 {
                self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
                recogniserOutlet.isEnabled = true
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0 {
                self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
                recogniserOutlet.isEnabled = false
            }
        }
    }



//To dismiss the keyboard

@IBAction func dismissPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
```

Comment: You should use this pod instead of manging the view manually everywhere in your project https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

Comment: You could put a breakpoint on `keyboardWillShow` in order to see what exactly is failing.